# Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) with multiple Active directories with no two way trust between them

Tags: active-directory, crm, adfs, adfs3.0, ifd

I've installed ADFS & AD on two Windows Server 2012 R2 machines.
I've managed to connect them together, and everything is working properly.
But how can I add more active directories to my ADFS configuration?
I'm ready to start everything from scratch.

In fact I want this feature to login any user in my site in any AD forest.
I looked in the internet but there is no any config to do this work. I want ADFS Config For this Work Contain Rules, Relays, and etc.

anyone know this config?

Answer (score 2):

If the ADFS server (which requires to be domain joined) is attached to one of your forests and the other forests have forest level trust (2-way) this would work seamlessly with no additional configuration.